¿Donde queda el archivo app.config de mi aplicación de consola/windows forms? .NET Framework 4.8
Bueno tengo una gran duda sobre ¿Porque cuando publico mi aplicación de consola o windows forms usando .net framework 4.8 al revisar los archivos generados no me genera o muestra mi archivo app.config?
Al publicarlo en una carpeta de un servidor de windows lo unico que genera seria lo siguiente:
1.- Carpeta de "Applications Files"
    - Esta carpeta tiene varias carpetas segun la version en la que vaya la app, la cual cada version tendria los siguientes archivos
        - NombreDeLaApp.application
        - NombreDeLaApp.exe.config.deploy
        - NombreDeLaApp.exe.deploy
        - NombreDeLaApp.exe.manifest
2.- Aplicacion con extension .application
3.- archivo setup

Por ejemplo, cuando creo una aplicacion web usando asp.net el archivo web.config si se genera al publicarlo y lo que quiero con esto de que se muestre el archivo app.config es que pueda cambiar el password de mi cadena de conexion cada que se actualice desde ese archivo, sin necesidad de cambiarlo desde el proyecto y volver a publicar mi aplicacion.
Alguien que tenga conocimiento sobre esto que me pueda ayudar? Gracias de antemano :)
P.D. Intente abriendo la carpeta "Applications Files" y despues la carpeta de la última actualización de mi app para abrir el archivo "NombreDeLaApp.exe.config.deploy" y ahí venia mi cadena de conexión, pero al modificarla y ejecutar mi aplicacion no se vieron reflejados los cambios, se supone  que se puede cambiar el password desde ese archivo si es que es lo mismo que el app.config pero no. Como mencione quiero hacer esto para no volver a publicar la aplicación y manejar los cambios de la conexión desde el archivo app.config pero no funcionó.

Estas usando ClickOnce ???

@Yussef Si, estas en lo correcto estoy usando ClickOnce

Lo que comentas es bastante común al trabajar con aplicaciones Windows Forms o de consola usando .NET Framework y ClickOnce para la publicación. Cuando publicas una aplicación usando ClickOnce, el archivo app.config se transforma en el archivo NombreDeLaApp.exe.config, que luego se renombra a NombreDeLaApp.exe.config.deploy durante el proceso de publicación. Este archivo contiene todas las configuraciones definidas en tu app.config.
Para resolver tu problema y poder modificar la cadena de conexión sin necesidad de volver a publicar la aplicación puedes hacer lo siguiente:
1. Configura tu proyecto para usar un archivo de configuración externo
Primero, asegúrate de que tu proyecto esté configurado para buscar configuraciones en un archivo externo.
Abre tu archivo app.config. Asegúrate de que tu cadena de conexión esté configurada en el archivo app.config.
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=user;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

2. Modifica el archivo .config.deploy en el servidor
Después de publicar tu aplicación y copiar los archivos al servidor, realiza los siguientes pasos:

Navega a la carpeta donde se encuentra la última versión de tu aplicación, dentro de la carpeta Applications Files.

Renombra el archivo quitando la extensión .deploy, dejándolo como NombreDeLaApp.exe.config.

Abre el archivo NombreDeLaApp.exe.config y realiza los cambios necesarios en la cadena de conexión.


3. Ejecuta tu aplicación
Ahora, cuando ejecutes tu aplicación, debería utilizar la cadena de conexión modificada en el archivo NombreDeLaApp.exe.config.
Te muestro un ejemplo:
Supongamos que tu aplicación se llama MiAplicacion.

Después de publicar, navega a Applications Files\MiAplicacion_1_0_0_0 (o la versión correspondiente).

Renombra MiAplicacion.exe.config.deploy a MiAplicacion.exe.config.

Abre MiAplicacion.exe.config y modifica la cadena de conexión según sea necesario.

Ejecuta MiAplicacion.application para iniciar tu aplicación.


Solución Alternativa:
Si no deseas renombrar el archivo cada vez que publicas una nueva versión, puedes modificar el archivo .config.deploy antes de publicar la nueva versión. Sin embargo, esta opción requiere que modifiques el archivo de configuración antes de cada publicación, lo cual puede no ser ideal si buscas flexibilidad.
Siguiendo estos pasos, deberías poder actualizar la cadena de conexión en el archivo de configuración sin necesidad de recompilar y republicar tu aplicación.

Intente tal cual las intrucciones que me dijiste, pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación esta no reconoce el cambio en el archivo exe.config, ya que actualice el password y aun sigue tomando el original

Tras renombrar de MiAplicacion.exe.config.deploy a MiAplicacion.exe.config una vez cambies los datos vuelve a poner el nombre original MiAplicacion.exe.config.deploy
